# Unable to use online prediction service with image input using a model saved from keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-ml

Consider the following code to create a saved_model

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Lambda
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

inp = Input((), dtype=tf.string, name="image_bytes")
net = Lambda(lambda t: tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.io.decode_jpeg(x), t, dtype=tf.uint8))(inp)
net = Lambda(lambda t: tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.io.encode_jpeg(x), t, dtype=tf.string), name="output")(net)

model = Model(inp, net, name="test_network")

tf.keras.experimental.export_saved_model(model, "runs/cmle_test_model", serving_only=True)
```

Now, I am trying to get an online prediction request to work with the payload

```
{"image_bytes":{"b64":"/9j/..."}}
```

full payload at https://gist.github.com/suyash/00d6846ab1a82e74f312ebb43b384c12

which errors out with

```
{
  "error": "Prediction failed: Error during model execution: AbortionError(code=StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT, details=\"Expected input[1] == 'test_network/output/map/TensorArrayUnstack/TensorListFromTensor/element_shape:output:0' to be a control input.\n\tIn {{node test_network/lambda/map/TensorArrayV2Stack/TensorListStack}}\n\t [[{{node StatefulPartitionedCall}}]]\n\t [[{{node StatefulPartitionedCall}}]]\")"
}
```

However, locally if I simply do

```
out = model(data)
```

it works fine

**UPDATE:**

I have something working with

```
inp = Input((), dtype=tf.string, name="image_bytes")
net = Lambda(lambda t: tf.expand_dims(tf.io.decode_jpeg(t[0]), 0))(inp)
net = Lambda(lambda t: tf.expand_dims(tf.io.encode_base64(tf.io.encode_jpeg(t[0])), 0), name="output")(net)
```

but that fixes the usable batch size for the service to 1. Ideally, I'd like to use the `Lambda` layer with `tf.map_fn`

Comment: Please share the complete code by adding code snippet or via github url.

Comment: Please try the very first snippet provided. It is supposed to be complete.